# how can we get benefit from sharding the data to speed the training time?

Tags: tensorflow

My main issue is : I have 204 GB training tfrecords for 2 million images, and 28GB for validation tf.records files, of 302900 images. it takes 8 hour to train one epoch and this will take 33 day for training. I want to speed that by using multiple threads and shards but I am little bit confused about couple of things.

In [tf.data.Dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) there is shard function , So in the documentation they mentioned the following about shard function :

> Creates a Dataset that includes only 1/num_shards of this dataset.
>
> This dataset operator is very useful when running distributed training, as it allows each worker to read a unique subset.
>
> When reading a single input file, you can skip elements as follows:

```
d = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(FLAGS.input_file)
d = d.shard(FLAGS.num_workers, FLAGS.worker_index)
d = d.repeat(FLAGS.num_epochs)
d = d.shuffle(FLAGS.shuffle_buffer_size)
d = d.map(parser_fn, num_parallel_calls=FLAGS.num_map_threads)
```

> Important caveats:
>
> Be sure to shard before you use any randomizing operator (such as shuffle).
>   Generally it is best if the shard operator is used early in the dataset pipeline. >For example, when reading from a set of TFRecord files, shard before converting >the dataset to input samples. This avoids reading every file on every worker. The >following is an example of an efficient sharding strategy within a complete >pipeline:

```
d = Dataset.list_files(FLAGS.pattern)
d = d.shard(FLAGS.num_workers, FLAGS.worker_index)
d = d.repeat(FLAGS.num_epochs)
d = d.shuffle(FLAGS.shuffle_buffer_size)
d = d.repeat()
d = d.interleave(tf.data.TFRecordDataset,
             cycle_length=FLAGS.num_readers, block_length=1)

d = d.map(parser_fn, num_parallel_calls=FLAGS.num_map_threads)
```

So my question regarding the code above is when I try to makes d.shards of my data using shard function, if I set the number of shards (num_workers)to 10 , I will have 10 splits of my data , then should I set the num_reader in d.interleave function to 10 to guarantee that each reader take one split from the 10 split?

and how I can control which split the function interleave will take? because if I set the shard_index (worker_index) in shard function to 1 it will give me the first split. Can anyone give me an idea how can I perform this distributed training using the above functions?

then what about the num_parallel_call . should I set it to 10 as well?

knowing that I have single tf.records file for training and another one for validation , I don't split the tf.records files into multiple files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, how come dataset is 204GB for only 2million images? I think your image is way too large. Try to resize the image. After all, you would probably need to resize it to 224 x 224 in the end.

Second, try to reduce the size of your model. your model could be either too deep or not efficient enough.

Third, try to parallelize your input reading process. It could the bottleneck.